# How to save a python dictionary with list keys to a file?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, save

How can I save a python dictionary with list keys to a file? I have tried json, but it says it only works with string keys, and my dictionary looks like this:

```
{(24222, 64130): 'whatever', (24270, 64130): 'whatever', (24240, 64130): 'whatever'}
```

And I have to keep in this form.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You pickle them.

Comment: @janos Can I transform them back to a list later?

Answer (score 2):

Convert your dictionary into string and write it into file.

```
dict_val = {(24222, 64130): 'whatever', (24270, 64130): 'whatever', (24240, 64130): 'whatever'}

with open('file.txt','w') as f:
     f.write(str(dict_val))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pickle

Python has a package named `pickle` with which you can store vanilla objects (and more advanced objects, although not everything), into a binary file.

You can do this with:

```
import pickle

with open('file.bin', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(your_dict, file)
```

later you can retrieve your dictionary with:

```
import pickle

with open('file.bin', 'rb') as file:
    your_dict = pickle.load(file)
```

Possible problems with pickle are that you can not pickle everything (not lambda expressions, etc.) and furthermore since you have some freedom to pickle arbitrary objects, unfortunately you will have to trust the file: a hacker could replace your file with a manipulated file through which they gain access to parts of your code you probably want to hide.

Furthermore pickle is an open format: it is specified, this means that you can manipulate a pickle for the good, but that a person can of course alter the file in a way you do not want/expect. So be careful with those files: do not let a user simply upload one, and inspect it.

## `repr` and `literal_eval`

Alternatively, you can use the `repr(..)` for tuples, integers, strings, etc. this will work fine. So if you write:

```
>>> repr(your_dict)
"{(24222, 64130): 'whatever', (24270, 64130): 'whatever', (24240, 64130): 'whatever'}"
```

we obtain a string that contains the textual representation. We can thus write it to a file like:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(repr(your_dict))
```

later we can use the `ast` package to load the literals again:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('file.txt') as file:
    your_dict = literal_eval(file.read())
```

The advantage of this, is that it is a readable format you can easily alter, and furthermore `literal_eval` will only parse literals, so it is safe to use.

Comment: This works but I think it's a good idea to mention the security issue with Pickle. We don't know, for example, if the OP is receiving this data from an untrusted source.

Comment: Thanks, I try this.

Comment: There's `shelve` which stores pickled objects in a file.

Answer (score 1):

While @WillemVanOnsem's solution is certainly more inline with what the OP is asking, the solution below illustrates how to save the dictionary to a file and retrieve it using strings:

```
s = {(24222, 64130): 'whatever', (24270, 64130): 'whatever', (24240, 64130): 'whatever'}
f = open('the_file.txt', 'w')
for a, b in s.items():
    f.write("{} {}\n".format(','.join(map(str, a)), b)

f.close()
#to retrieve:
data = {tuple(map(int, a.split(','))):b for a, b in [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('the_file.txt')]}
```